# for each jQuery loop to split into multiple strings for php parsing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, parsing

I'm trying to take values from a table and put them into a string and send them to a php page for logging to a database, however there will be multiple rows need to be inserted so i need to split the values into multiple strings to send if that makes (any) sense?

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#submit').live('click',function(){ 
                var supp_short_code=$('.supp_short_code').text();
                var project_ref=$('.project_ref').text();
                var om_part_no=$('.om_part_no').text();
                var description=$('.description').text();
                var cost_of_items=$('.cost_of_items').text();
                var cost_total=$('.cost_total').text();
                var dataString = 'string=//' + supp_short_code + '//' + project_ref + '//' + om_part_no + '//' + description + '//' + cost_of_items + '//' + cost_total

                $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "order.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function()
                        {
                            alert("Order Submitted");
                        }
                    });
            });
```

but what i'm saying that there may be 2 or 5 or 12 values in each of the variables!? My plan is to send a string to the php, get the php to parse the values between the "//" and to insert them into separate variables for a mysql query. If someone can think of a better way to do this, please tell me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transport it as JSON string.

```
[{"row": 1, "supp_short_code" : blah blah....}, {"row": 2, ....} ....]
```

Now this means you have to go through the rows one by one. Select on all the rows and construct your datastring one line at a time, by appending onto the JSON string. This will make the PHP parsing much easier.

```
var dataString = '['
$('#table tr').each(function(
    var supp_short_code = $(this).filter('.supp_short_code').text();
    // and so on.
    if (index > 0) {
        dataString += ','
    }
    dataString += '{"row": index, "supp_short_code": supp_short_code, .... }';
});
dataString += ']'
```

Comment: this sounds promising! what i dont understand is how i make the jQuery see that there have been 2 rows in the table rather than just one (for ex), so it knows to send more rows via json...?

Comment: There I put up something to help you iterate through each row.